# How to do this without declaring 200 variables?

Tags: string, delphi, variables, pascal

I think that there is a solution for my problem but I didn't find it, can you help me?

I want to do something like this:

```
var
  a, b, c: string;
  d: integer;
begin
  a := StringGrid1.Cells[1,1];
  b := StringGrid1.Cells[2,1];
  c := StringGrid1.Cells[3,1];
  d := StrToInt(a) + StrToInt(b) + StrToInt(c);
  StringGrid1.Cells[4,1] := IntToStr(d);
end;
```

But now I need to declare 200 string variables like in this example. Is there anyway a 'shortcut' for this?

This is the loop that I tried:

```
var
  x: integer;
begin
  for x := 1 to 200 do 
  begin 
    Form2.StringGrid1.Cells[3,209] := IntToStr(x);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i tried with a loop but nothing has changed

Comment: Please show your attempt at loops.

Comment: If you "tried it with a loop", please [edit] your question to include that effort as well.

Comment: You need to learn how to program. Find a very basic book and read the section on loops more carefully.

Comment: Your loop does no addition. How would you expect it to work? You just change an integer to a string and then replace the same cells content with that string 200 times.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Pascal+tutorial

Answer (score 8):

```
var
  Total: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Total := 0;
  for I := 1 to 3 do
    Inc(Total, StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[I, 1]));
  StringGrid1.Cells[4, 1] := IntToStr(Total);
end;
```

Comment: Then you should accept it as an answer an invite @NGLN to a beer